# .gitignore for Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04 not ignoring certain files. [tried the usual solutions]

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitignore

git always shows me these files for my AS projects.

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   .idea/.name
    modified:   .idea/compiler.xml
    deleted:    .idea/encodings.xml
    modified:   .idea/gradle.xml
    modified:   .idea/misc.xml
    modified:   .idea/modules.xml
    deleted:    .idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml
    modified:   .idea/vcs.xml
    deleted:    Pronto.iml
    modified:   app/app.iml
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ***-****.iml
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I have tried the approaches like [.gitignore](https://gist.github.com/iainconnor/8605514)
using git rm to remove cache. etc.

my .gitignore matches the link to the point.

Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.gitignore` only ignores untracked files. Since your files are already tracked by git, you can call `git rm --cached` on those files to remove them from git index but keep them in working tree.

Comment: that command is quite unsettling, ive used it before..for some reason it generates a very long list of all my files..in staged mode [even xmls!] and then my app is no longer recognized by android studio as a gradle project.